# Get Data from mutile table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 table, I want to get Data from those table using join.
This is my table structure and data in these 3 tables.

I am using **MS Sql server**.

[image]

```
Year    Month      TotalNewCaseAmount   TotalNewCaseCount   TotalClosingAmount   TotalReturnCount   TotalClosingAmount   TotalReturnCount  

2016    Januray     146825.91           1973                54774.41                147                 299.35              41

2016    Fabuary     129453.30           5384                46443.99                7                   7568.21             123

2016    March       21412.07            3198                Null                    Null                78.83               73

2016    April       0.00                5                   Null                    Null                Null                NULL
```

I don't know which join will me this result, I have tried CROSS join, But it will give me 36 row.

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN, not CROSS JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will do:

```
;WITH Table1 AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(2016, 'Januray',  146825.91, 1973),
(2016, 'Fabuary',  129453.30, 5384),
(2016, 'March',    21412.07, 3198),
(2016, 'April',    0.00, 5)
) as t ([Year], [Month], TotalNewCaseAmount, TotalNewCaseCount)
), Table2 AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(2016, 'Januray', 54774.41, 147),
(2016, 'Fabuary', 46443.99, 7)
) as t ([Year], [Month], TotalClosingAmount, TotalClosingCount)
), Table3 AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(2016, 'Januray', 299.35, 41),
(2016, 'Fabuary', 7568.21, 123),
(2016, 'March', 78.83, 73)
) as t ([Year], [Month], TotalReturnAmount, TotalReturnCount)
)

SELECT  t1.[Year],
        t1.[Month],
        t1.TotalNewCaseAmount,
        t1.TotalNewCaseCount,
        t2.TotalClosingAmount,
        t2.TotalClosingCount,
        t3.TotalReturnAmount,
        t3.TotalReturnCount  
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.[Year] = t2.[Year] AND t1.[Month] = t2.[Month]
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
    ON t1.[Year] = t3.[Year] AND t1.[Month] = t3.[Month]
```

Output:

```
Year    Month   TotalNewCaseAmount  TotalNewCaseCount   TotalClosingAmount  TotalClosingCount   TotalReturnAmount   TotalReturnCount
2016    Januray 146825.91           1973                54774.41            147                 299.35              41
2016    Fabuary 129453.30           5384                46443.99            7                   7568.21             123
2016    March   21412.07            3198                NULL                NULL                78.83               73
2016    April   0.00                5                   NULL                NULL                NULL                NULL
```

Just change `table1`, `table2` and `table3` to your actual table names.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
select
t1.*,
t2.TotalClosingAmount,
t2.TotalClosingCount,
t3.TotalRetrunAmount,
t3.TotalReturnCount
from 
Table1 t1
left join 
Table2 t2 on t1.year=t2.year
and t1.month=t2.month
left join 
Table3 t3 on t1.year=t3.year
and t1.month=t3.month
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
    select year,month, totalnewcasesamount,totalnewcasescount,
    totalclosingamount,totalclosingcount,totlareturnamopunt,totalreturncount   

    from table1 full outer join 
    table2
    on table1.year=table2.year
    and table1.month=table2.month    
    full outer join table3
    on table1.year=table3.year
    and table1.month=table3.month
    where table1.year is not null
    and table1.month is not nulll
```